# How do I get a custom block's creation date in the block bundle template file?

Tags: entities, blocks

I have created a custom block type in Drupal 8, and now I want to fetch block creation/publish date in block bundle twig file. I tried fetching it using content.revision_created but can't get it. I can get title and other custom fields but not date. may be because of the reason it's protected. How do I get the block creation date?